# Why does creating an Anaconda Virtual Environment in Pycharm give a Time Out error?

Tags: python, python3, anaconda, pycharm

In Pycharm, whenever I try to create a Conda virtual environment, I am getting Time Out errors. Here is how I am creating the virtual environment:

[image: Pycharm Conda Virtual Environment]

And this is the error message I receive no matter how many times I try:

[image: Pycharm Error Message]

And here is the error message:

```
Solving environment: ...working... failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/pro/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))
```

If it is because Path variables aren't set, then can someone guide me on how and what to set?

Comment: This is likely an error with SSL (an issue which seems to pop up rather frequently  in Anaconda). As a suggestion, try installing an appropriate version of SSL from [Shining Light Productions](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)

Comment: Note that you can get the paths used by Anaconda with `echo %PATH%` at an Anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 0):

This particular case is covered by the following ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35141

IDE doesn't activate base conda in `C:\ProgramData` before creating the environment causing SSLError.